# phpmailer envia email para mim mesmo

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
<?php

require 'funcoes/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$email = $_POST['email'];

$nome = $_POST['nome'];

$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];

$mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];



$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;


$mail->isSMTP(); 

$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 


$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 


$mail->Username = 'meuemail';  


$mail->Password = 'senha';   


$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';     


$mail->Port = 587;         

$mail->From = $email; 

$mail->Sender = $email; 

$mail->FromName = $nome; 


$mail->AddAddress('meuemail', 'Milton Viziak');

$mail->AddAddress('meuemail');


$mail->Subject = $titulo;

$mail->Body    = $mensagem;


if(!$mail->send()) {

    echo 'Message could not be sent.';

    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;

} else {

    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

minha duvida é porque eu estou enviando email para min mesmo se eu coloco o from e o sender com o email recebido no formulario ?

Comment: o `AddAddress` não pode ser o seu email, porque `AddAddress` é o destinatário, nesse campo informe o destinatário que você quer, no caso o retorno do formulário.

Comment: mas o destinatário no caso sou eu.e como assim informa o retorno do formulario ?

Comment: Você deve colocar  a variavel `$email` no `$mail->AddAddress($email, 'Milton Viziak');`

Comment: mas a variavel $email é só o email do cara que preencheu o formulario.

Comment: então, afinal, para qual email deve ser enviado?

Comment: Se o destinatário é você é claro que você mesmo vai receber o email.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente fazer desta forma, pois se o e-mail for inválido o e-mail não será enviado:

```
$mail->SetFrom((filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false) ? $email : 
'linker83@gmail.com' , (string) $nome);
//$mail->AddReplyTo((filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false) ? $email : 
'linker83@gmail.com', (string) $nome);

//aqui o nome de quem envia
$mail->FromName = $nome; //nome de quem envia
```

Corrija a linha abaixo, pois o usuário que deve ser o receptor da mensagem, correto?

```
$mail->AddAddress('linker83@gmail.com', 'Milton Viziak');
```

E apague esta linha duplicada em baixo, a menos que você queira receber uma cópia:

```
// $mail->AddAddress('seuemail@gmail.com');
```

E acrescente estas linhas se deseja enviar em formato HTML:

```
$Email->WordWrap = 50;
$Email->IsHTML(true);
```

Comment: `$mail->From = "miltonviziak@yahoo.com.br"; 
$mail->FromName = "Ursula belchior";
//Define o destinatario
$mail->AddAddress('linker83@gmail.com', 'Milton Viziak');

$mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
$mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)`

Comment: la no email ele não aparece no remetente o "miltonviziak@yahoo.com.br" ele ta aparecendo o linker83@gmail.com.

Comment: e não era pra aparece o email do from la no remetente ?o nome aparece certo aparece ursula mesmo agora o email não

Comment: Como disse, você está invertendo.

Comment: fiz isso.Ele não envia email nenhum.

Comment: Escreve na sua pergunta quais são os seus e-mails 1.remetente 2.receptor 3.resposta, 4.sistema, porque parece que nem você sabe o que vc quer. Vc leu os comentários do código? Vc sabe qual é a diferença entre remetende e destinatário?

Comment: remetente = quem envia o email | 
receptor / destinatário = quem recebe a mensagem | sistema = conta que fará o serviço de entrega | resposta = qual email receberá uma resposta do receptor

Comment: fiz o formulario de contato. nele pego o nome, o email, o titulo e a mensagem.e esse formulario vai enviar para o meu email que é o linker83.só que eu envio o contato pelo formulario.mas só que eu digito qualquer email valido e ele não aparece.a unica coisa que aparece é que ele envia de min mesmo.

Comment: [link](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/sem_titulo-jpg--5178). Olha ai meu erro e la no lugar do DE: Ursula Belchior não é aquele email que eu coloco coloco outro

Comment: Entendi o seu problema, você quer receber o email como se fosse do cliente. Então, é só colocar o email do cliente no Sender.

Comment: Pelo que estou vendo a sua configuração estava certa, vc está digitando que email no formulário de contato?

Comment: o email do cliente.

Comment: $mail->From = 'miltonviziak@yahoo.com.br';
$mail->FromName = 'Ursula';
$mail->addAddress('example@gmail.com', 'Milton Viziak');

Comment: no From que é o de ta o miltonviziak mas ta enviando como se fosse o linker que ta igual na imagen que eu te mandei.e pela consiguração é para aparecer De: miltonviziak para:linker83

Comment: [link](http://dummyscodes.blogspot.com.br/2014/08/php-send-mail-with-xampp-localhost.html) o meu ta configurado igual desse link

Comment: não deu certo continua a mesma coisa.Sera que pode ter algum erro na classe do phpmailer ?o metedo AddAddress esta sobrescrevendo a variavel $From ?